# C++ syntax: Object* foo(0);

Tags: c++, syntax

I can't think of a better title than that because I really don't understand what that line should mean.
So, it's in a while loop inside a function, and here it is once again:

```
  Object* foo(0);
```

If it's a declaration of a pointer variable, what in the world is that `(0)` thing? the `foo` really is used as a variable a few lines later, like so: `foo=new Something;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those places where C++ is not C. In C++,

```
int i(47);
```

is equivalent (at least in this context) to:

```
int i = 47;
```

Strictly speaking, it constructs an  object called `i` of class `int` and calls a constructor to initialize the object. So,

```
Object * foo(0);
```

is exactly the same as

```
Object * foo = 0;
```

It constructs an object called `foo` of class "pointer-to-Object" (here, `Object` is a type name, so it's actually a Class not an object) and uses a constructor to initialize the new object.

//B

Answer (score 7):

It's initializing the pointer to `NULL`.

Equivalent to:

```
Object* foo = NULL;
```

or

```
Object* foo = 0; // since NULL is defined as 0
```

Comment: @jrok where do you see an assignment?

Answer (score 3):

It declares a pointer to `Object` and initializes it with 0 (NULL).

Comment: For Objects, initialization / assignment can take different paths. For pointers, is this also the case?

Comment: They're different things. I'm not sure what you mean?